# Jinja2 template support in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, templates, pydev, jinja2

Using the Eclipse keybinding Shift-Ctrl+F (Format) in Python (with help from PyDev), Javascript or plain HTML files works as expected.
Jinja2 templates however, become a mess. Is there a solution to solve or easily work around this?

Answer (score 3):

As Jinja2 seems very close to Django templates, it may be worth using the Django templates editor (it's distributed along with Aptana Studio 3 -- you just have to change the file association to open html files with that editor in the file association).